# wordpress - woocommerce- woocommerce_api_authentication_error on api

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I’m using the woocommerce api for my application, i’ve created the keys and apis and it did work fine , it authenticate and return the data via the api .

It’s been two days that it doesn’t connect any more , I’ve made a new api key but the same result.
I get this message when I run the url :

```
{"errors":[{"code":"woocommerce_api_authentication_error","message":"\u06a9\u0644\u06cc\u062f \u06cc\u06a9 \u0645\u0646\u0638\u0648\u0631\u0647 \u0646\u0627\u0645\u0639\u062a\u0628\u0631 \u0627\u0633\u062a. \u06a9\u0644\u06cc\u062f \u0642\u0628\u0644\u0627 \u0627\u0633\u062a\u0641\u0627\u062f\u0647 \u0634\u062f\u0647 \u0627\u0633\u062a."}]}
```

it says woocommerce_api_authentication_error , but I've created new keys and I'm sure the keys are correct .

can you help me . this is a sample code of mine :

```
    $options = array(
‘debug’ => true,
‘return_as_array’ => false,
‘validate_url’ => false,
‘timeout’ => 30,
‘ssl_verify’ => false,
);

$client = new WC_API_Client(‘http://nodasht.com’,
“ck_4c25b06d7a9e507fbdeb06e338e20a2db1f7cc43”,
“cs_b89c9152510beb3cd915942cc4f33b91b720d62e”, $options);

$res = $client->products->get($row->ID);
$product = $res->product;
```

Answer (score -1):

If you google bits of your message like this part [\u06a9](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/06a9/index.htm) you will be able to find out what the message is , thus know what the actual problem is.